# How to solve systems of polynomial inequalities?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I am currently working on a project that deals with systems of inequalities and so far I have found algorithms for the basic case of a system of inequalities as well as the non-strict linear inequalities (using Linear Programming). I was wondering if there is an algorithm that will help solve a system of polynomial inequalities besides Cylindrical Decomposition. If there isn't one for both the strict/non-strict versions, an algorithm for just one will suffice.

Comment: The study of these systems is called "Real Semialgebraic Geometry". Unfortunately, cylindrical decomposition is the best algorithm I'm aware of for solving them. But googling "Real Semialgebraic Geometry" may turn something up.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to find other algorithms to compare them to cylindrical decomposition. More than efficiency I'm looking at implementability (it's a computer science problem). Thanks for your input though!

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inequality_(mathematics)&oldid=953334519#General_existence_theorems) describes another method for solving systems of polynomial inequalities, but I'm not sure if it's accurate.